# Wildcard match and replace in Java

Tags: java, regex, wildcard

I want to check a string to see if it contains $wildcard$, and ONLY if it does I want to extract the value between the "$ $", which I'll use to retrieve a replacement. Then replace the full new string (removing the $ $ as well)

Edit: managed to get this working [demo](https://ideone.com/mFQ8Ra)

```
String subject = "test/$name$/something";
String replace = "foo_bar";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\$).*?(\\$)");
Matcher m = regex.matcher(subject);

StringBuffer b= new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
     String something = m.group(0);
     System.out.println(something);
     m.appendReplacement(b, replace);
}
m.appendTail(b);
String replaced = b.toString();
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Gives me the output of

```
$name$
test/foo_bar/something
```

I could substring to remove the lead/trailing $ but is there a way to split these into groups so I can just get what is between $ $. But also ensuring that the initial check ensures it has a start and end $

Comment: Why have you tried so far?

Comment: `subject_final = subject.replaceAll("\\$[^$]+\\$", replace);`

Comment: something in here will likely answer your question: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove unnecessary capturing groups from both `\\$`, set the capturing group on the pattern that matches what is between two `$` chars (and the most efficient construct to use here is a negated character class `[^$]`), and then just grab the value of `.group(1)`:

```
String subject = "test/$name$/something";
String replace = "foo_bar";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\$([^$]*)\\$"); // ONLY 1 GROUP ROUND [^$]*
Matcher m = regex.matcher(subject);
StringBuffer b= new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    String something = m.group(1); // ACCESS GROUP 1
    System.out.println(something);
    m.appendReplacement(b, replace);
}
m.appendTail(b);
String replaced = b.toString();
System.out.println(replaced);
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/9GIXx2)

Result:

```
name
test/foo_bar/something
```

**Pattern details**

- `\\$` - a `$` char
- `([^$]*)`  - [**Capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1 matching zero or more chars other than `$` char
- `\\$` - a `$` char.

Answer (score 1):

Add another matching group for the content of the tag:

```
Pattern.compile("(\\$)(.*?)(\\$)");
```

Answer (score 0):

It has *slightly* different syntax that you're asking for, but check out Apache Commons Text: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StrSubstitutor.html

This will let you do things like:

```
    Map<String,String> substitutions = ImmutableMap.of("name", "foo_bar");
    String template = "/test/${name}/something";
    StrSubstitutor substitutor = new StrSubstitutor(substitutions);
    System.out.println(substitutor.replace(template));
```

You could build your own Map to populate with your substitution values.

Comment: Looks like a interesting alternative, however it is reading from a config file that others can $ $ patterns to. So I wouldnt always know whats between them. Any additions would require a code change